# Why dynamic links in React Native are opening the browser first?

Tags: react-native, mobile, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to communicate two React Native apps using Firebase Dynamic Links, only in Android.

When I execute openLink with the URL of the other, I see the browser for a second, and then it opens the other app well.

I don't want to see an intermediate browser before open the other app.

I'm having that issue from app A to B, and viceversa.

So, why is the browser opening first? And how can I configure the apps in order to not open the browser?

Answer (score 2):

it's default behavior of android devices.
usually if any link supported by app and its set default to open link then it will open directly otherwise android system opens browser and based on Link URI scheme navigate to app.

there is one solution,
You can create module (intent activity) which will launch that app directly.
Steps to follow

1. pass data from js to native module and from that use Intent class, set data and start it.
   this was for Android use case.